# To prove the recurrence by substitution method $T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2$

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation

I have done the proof until the point when $T(n) \leq cn^{\log7}$.

But when it comes to finding the value of constant $c$, I am getting stuck.

The given recurrence relation is $T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2$.

Since we already calculated the solution above which is $cn^{\log 7}$.

Inductive step:

Now we have to prove that $T(n) \leq c n^{\log7}$ where $c$ is a positive constant.
If we consider that the solution holds good for $n/2$ then we can prove that it works  for $n$ also: 
$$T(n/2) \leq c(n/2)^{\log7}.$$
Substituting these values in the recurrence relation:

$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &\leq 7c/(2)^{\log7} \times (n)^{\log7} + n^2 \\
     &\leq cn^{\log7}, \text{ since $7/(2)^{\log7}$  is constant so can be ignored and $cn^{\log7} \gg n^2$ for large $n$} \\
     &\leq cn^{\log7} \text{ assuming $c$ is a constant $\geq 1$.}
\end{align*}
$$

Finally to find constant $c$,

$$(7/(2)^{\log7}) \times cn^{\log7} + n^2 \leq cn^{\log7}. $$

I am not able to find appropriate $c$ for which the condition holds true.

Answer (score 4):

You're headed in the right direction, but you need an intermediate step. Permit me to simplify things a bit by defining $\lg n = \log_2n$.

**A Dead End**

Your substitution method, where you want to establish that $T(n) \le cn^{\lg7}$ inductively, using the assumption $T(n/2)\le c(n/2)^{\lg 7}$ runs into problems, as you've already seen. Here's what happens:
$$\begin{align}
T(n) &= 7T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+n^2&\text{by definition}\\
 &\le 7\left[c\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{lg7}\right]+n^2&\text{by the inductive assumption}\\
 &=7\left[c\frac{n^{\lg7}}{7}\right]+n^2&\text{since $2^{lg 7}=7$}\\
 &=c\,n^{\lg7}+n^2
\end{align}$$
and you'll obviously never be able to find a $c$ for which $c\,n^{\lg7}+n^2\le c\,n^{\lg 7}$.

**A Way Out**

The problem is that the $n^2$ term is messing you up. If it weren't there, then substitution would work. Suppose, for instance, that we had the simpler recurrence $S(n)=7\,S(n/2)$. Now life would be easy, since then the proof above would go through nicely. Assume that $S(n)\le c\,n^{\lg7}$. Then we'd have
$$\begin{align}
S(n) &= 7S\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)&\text{by definition}\\
 &\le 7\left[c\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{lg7}\right]&\text{by the inductive assumption}\\
 &=7\left[c\frac{n^{\lg7}}{7}\right]\\
 &=c\,n^{\lg7}&\text{as required}
\end{align}$$
and if you do this again and again, driving $n$ down to $1$, you'll find that you can choose any $c\ge S(1)$.

**Transforming the Dead End Into the Way Out**

Let's make the $n^2$ term go away. Let $S(n) = T(n)+k\,n^2$. Then from
$$
T(n)=7\,T(n/2)+n^2
$$
we have, substituting and simplifying,
$$\begin{align}
S(n)-k\,n^2&=7\,[S(n/2)-k(n/2)^2]+n^2&\text{and so}\\
S(n) &= 7\,S(n/2)+n^2(k-7k/4+1)
\end{align}$$
and it's not hard to see that $k=4/3$ will make the $n^2$ term vanish, giving the $S$ recurrence we just solved above. Putting these together we have
$$
T(n)+\frac{4}{3}n^2=S(n)\le c\,n^{\lg7}
$$
and so
$$
T(n)\le c\,n^{\lg7}-\frac{4}{3}n^2<c\,n^{\lg7}
$$

**Lessons Learned**

Truth to tell, I'd attack this problem by iterative expansion, namely the way Yuval did it in his answer, but these "substitution method" questions come up often enough that I thought this cautionary tale was warranted. The lessons to be learned here are

- The method of substitution often doesn't work when applied to a recurrence relation.
- It always applies to recurrences of the form $S(n)=p\,S(n/q)$ as long as $q\ne0$
- A useful tool to have in your kit is knowing that sometimes you can transform a complicated recurrence into a simple one by suitable addition (or, sometimes, multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n$ is a power of $2$, say $n = 2^k$, and suppose $T(1) = 1$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 7T(n/2) + n^2 \\ &= 7^2T(n/2^2) + 7(n/2)^2 + n^2 \\ &=
7^3T(n/2^3) + 7^2(n/2^2)^2 + 7(n/2)^2 + n^2 \\ &=\cdots \\ &=
7^k + 7^{k-1} 4^1 + \cdots + 7^1 4^{k-1} + 4^k \\ &=
7^k \left(1 + \frac{4}{7} + \cdots + \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^k\right) \\ &=
7^k \frac{1-(4/7)^{k+1}}{1-4/7} \\ &=
(1 - (4/7)^{k+1}) \frac{7}{3} 7^k \\ &=
\left(1 - \tfrac{4}{7} n^{\log_2 (4/7)} \right) \frac{7}{3} n^{\log_2 7}.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore for $n = 2^k$,
$$ T(n) \sim \frac{7}{3} n^{\log_2 7}. $$

Comment: I have a doubt here : when we substitute n/2 in place of n calculating T(n/2) = 7 T(n/4) +(n/2)^2 , and after putting the value of T(n/2) in original equation it should be  7^2T(n/4) + (n/2)^2 + n^2                                                But in your proof above its: 7^2T(n/2^2)+7(n/2)^2+n^2. I want to know where is this extra 7 coming from (I mean 7(n/2)^2)

Comment: The extra $7$ is there since $7T(n/2) = 7(7T(n/4) + (n/2)^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate $T(2^k)$, you first start with T(1), which gets multiplied by 7 k times, giving $T(1)·7^k$.

But when you calculated T(2), you added a term $n^2 = 2^2$, which gets multiplied by 7 (k-1) times, giving $2^2·7^(k-1) = 7^k·(4/7)$.

When you calculated T(4), you added a term $n^2 = 4^2$, which gets multiplied by 7 (k-2) times, giving $4^2·7^(k-2) = 7^k·(4/7)^2$.

The same happens for the other intermediate terms, so your result is $7^k$, multiplied by (T (1) + (4/7) + (4/7)^2 + (4/7)^3 + (4/7)^4 ...), which is a geometric series with a sum of T (1) + 4/3. So c = T (1) + 4/3.

(A bit of care is needed: T (1) + 4/3 is the limit, but you asked for an upper bound. In this case since the values add up, the limit is the upper bound, but that wouldn't work for $T(n) = 7·T(n/2) - n^2$. )

You can use this approach for many similar recurrences. And it will show a problem instantly for the recurrence $T(n) = 7·T(n/2) + n^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the master theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

by case 1, if $f(n)= O(n^{2<{log_{2}7}})$ then $T(n)= O(n^{log_{2}7})$

Comment: OP has got this already. He wants to determine the constant factor, so this isn't helpful at all.